# how to nginx regex in map to extract value of a key in json

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a json request body which comes to nginx

```
{
    "studentName": "John",
    "studentId": "100",
    "narks": "100"
}
```

I am using NGINX $map to extract the value of studentName and map it to variable .
for now i am using manually to extract the known values

```
map $request_body $student_uid {
    
    default "john"
    ~*"john" "john";
    ~*"jack" "jack";
    ~*"jill" "jill";
    }
```

I have to extract the studentname and store in the student_uid values ..what will be the regex for doing that ? Prefer not to have any extra nginx module just for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `map` block to extract `studentName` JSON field from the request body:

```
map $request_body $student_name {
    ~\"studentName\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"    $1;
}
```

And if you want to combine this with your previous question, you can chain two `map` blocks:

```
map $request_body $student_name {
    ~\"studentName\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"    $1;
}
map $student_name $student_status {
    Bob        special;
    Alice      special;
    John       regular;
    ...
}
```

**Update**

If your JSON field could contain a shielded double quote, for example

```
{
    "studentName": "Mike \"Iron\" Tyson",
    "studentId": "100",
    "marks": "100"
}
```

the above regex would capture only the first part of the field (`Mike \` for the above example). To capture the whole field you'll need a more complex regex:

```
map $request_body $student_name {
    \"studentName\"\s*:\s*\"((?:[^\\\"]|\\.)*)\"    $1;
}
```

Comment: are you missing a " in the expression somewhere?

Comment: @Janier No, didn't missing anything. Tested this expression and can confirm it correctly extracts student name from your JSON example.

Comment: @Janier Updated the regex to work with JSON fields containing double quotes. Maybe you don't need it for you particular case, but I leave it here as an example of how to extract any JSON field from the request body including those with double quotes.